# Eclipse JAVA separate unit test and integration test

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

i m upgrading a project that contain only integration test wrote in JAVA.

Now we are going to write unit test, so i decide to create src/it/java folder to put all existing tests and wrote new unit test in src/test/java

I have use surfire and build-helper to do that.

in command line i can run

mvn clean install and only src/test/java directory are read for test

when i m doing

mvn -Pintegration-test clean install i see that test in src/it/java are read for test

so all work fine in command line.

Now i would like to import my project on eclipe. And when i m doing that only src/test/java is use as source folder.
How can i set up pom.xml to have src/test/java and src/it/java as source folder?

**here is my builder plugin conf

```
<plugin>    
<groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>     
<artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>1.8</version>
<executions>         
    <execution>             
      <id>add-test-source</id>       
      <phase>process-resources</phase>             
      <goals>                 
           <goal>add-test-source</goal>             
      </goals>             
      <configuration>                 
             <sources>                     
       <source>src/it/java</source>                 
         </sources>             
      </configuration>         
    </execution>     
</executions>
</plugin>
```

thanks a lot!

Answer (score 8):

There are in general three ways of solving such problem.

Using a separate folder for integration tests as you already decided to use.

```
.
|-- pom.xml
`-- src
    |-- it
    |   `-- java
    |       `-- com
    |           `-- soebes
    |               `-- maui
    |                   `-- it
    |                       `-- BitMaskIT.java
    |-- main
    |   `-- java
    |       `-- com
    |           `-- soebes
    |               `-- maui
    |                   `-- it
    |                       `-- BitMask.java
    `-- test
        `-- java
            `-- com
                `-- soebes
                    `-- maui
                        `-- it
                            `-- BitMaskTest.java
```

To get this working correctly in Eclipse you need to use the build-helper-maven-plugin which
you already suggested:

```
 <plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.8</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>add-test-source</id>
        <!--
            This will help m2eclipse to recognize the folder as source
            folder after update project configuration.
            Based on comment updated.
        -->
        <phase>validate</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>add-test-source</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <sources>
            <source>src/it/java</source>
          </sources>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

But as you can see this takes several supplemental configuration in your pom file.

Apart from the above the usage of maven-surefire-plugin for integration tests is simply wrong, cause maven-surefire-plugin is intended for unit tests and **not** for integration tests so better is to go with [maven-failsafe-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/) for integration tests.

Best is to following the naming conventions for unit and integration tests. In 
[maven-surefire-plugin the unit tests follow the following convention](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#includes):

```
- *Test.java
- *TestCase.java
- Test*.java
```

whereas the integration tests in [maven-failsafe-plugin follow the following convention:](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/integration-test-mojo.html#includes)

```
- *IT.java
- *ITCase.java
- IT*.java
```

```
.
|-- pom.xml
`-- src
    |-- main
    |   `-- java
    |       `-- com
    |           `-- soebes
    |               `-- maui
    |                   `-- it
    |                       `-- BitMask.java
    `-- test
        `-- java
            `-- com
                `-- soebes
                    `-- maui
                        `-- it
                            |-- BitMaskIT.java
                            `-- BitMaskTest.java
```

But sometimes much more better to make a separate module which contains only the
integration tests to separate them from the unit tests. This might be helpfull if
the integration tests have different configuration than the unit tests.

So making the structure like this:

```
 +-- root (pom.xml)
     +--- mod-it (pom.xml)
     +--- mod-core (pom.xml)
```

You should follow the naming convention in the `mod-it` to use the maven-failsafe-plugin
and correctly execute integration tests in the `integration-test` phase of the maven
build life-cycle.

Comment: thank you for your reply, in fact i had already add builder-helper-plugin but eclipse don't recognize src/it/java folder as source, i need to add it manually, does i need to install something on eclipse ? i have test to add testsourcedirectory in pom.xml but it replace the first one src/test/java :) and i can't add this markup twice...:(

Comment: I had to bind `build-helper-maven-plugin` to `<phase>validate</phase>`.  The above `<phase>process-resources</phase>` did not work for me.  Otherwise, this plugin solved this problem for me.  Eclipse now displays `src/it/java` in its own source folder.

Answer (score -2):

You will need to add the **src/it/java** folder manually in Eclipse via:

*Project Properties* -> *Java Build Path* -> *Source tab* -> *Add Folder*.

Comment: yes i now but what i want its doing this action automaticaly when i importing the project?